# playing media element when lock screen xamarin forms

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

I am Using Xamarin forms for play some music , when I lock my phone, the audio will stop. how should I Handel ? I do not want music pause

{

MediaElement KeepScreenOn="True"  x:FieldModifier="Public" Source="Voice.mp3"  AutoPlay="False" ShowsPlaybackControls="True" x:Name="MyMedia"

}

Answer (score 0):

`MediaElement` is currently experimental, I cannot found this feature play the music when lock screen, but you can use [CrossMediaManager](https://github.com/Baseflow/XamarinMediaManager), It is support the play the music when lock screen by default.

Just Used a Button to invoke the play method.

```
 <Button Text="play" Clicked="Button_Clicked"></Button>
```

```
 private async void Button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            await CrossMediaManager.Current.Play("https://ia800806.us.archive.org/15/items/Mp3Playlist_555/AaronNeville-CrazyLove.mp3");
        }
```

Note:when add `CrossMediaManager.Current.Init(this);` in your `OnCreate` method of `MainActivity.cs`. Please do not forget the set the Target Framework to Android 9.0 or later.

Comment: @Ashkan Are there any update for this issue? If the reply is helpful, please accept it as answer(click the “✔” in the upper left corner of this answer), it will help others who have similar issue.

Comment: Have you got the solution?? I have tried CrossMediaManager but not working for me

Comment: What is issue that you occured? When lock screen xamarin forms, the media cannot be played?

Comment: I have created widget for playing audio, what I want is when I pause audio in widget it should pause that in app too and vice versa, but it's not working.